# Using Protobuf Client from Java Example

Tags: servicestack

We're trying to interface with our ServiceStack REST Server from a linux Java integration, using Protobuf to increase the speed of transmission.

We have found the JsonServiceClient implementation in Java, but can't find a Protobuf equivalent or examples of others doing this.

Questions
1. Is there one?
2. If not, is there any examples of how to use Protobuf from a Java client?
3. Is there possibly any libraries already that allow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack only provides the [Java JsonServiceClient](http://docs.servicestack.net/java-add-servicestack-reference#jsonserviceclient-api) library, i.e. there is no ProtoBuf ServiceClient for Java.

Comment: OK fair enough. Would you have any suggestions or materials about how we would write our own client to query using protocol from the servicestack rest server?

Comment: @molc ServiceStack APIs are just plain HTTP APIs, so you just need to send a serialised Request Body to the Services Route, the major effort will be with the Java/C# ProtoBuf interop, where you’ll need to serialize a ProtoBuf payload in Java that can be deserialized directly into a ProtoBuf DTO taking into account the mapping of Java/C# primitive data types.